# How to express Postgres arrays with Scala Slick

Tags: scala, slick

I have a table in Postgres 9.5 with this structure:

```
my_table (id Integer, images_ranks image_rank[]);
```

where `image_rank` is:

```
CREATE TYPE image_rank AS (image_url text, thumbnail_rank integer);
```

I am struggling to express something like that in Slick (3.1):

```
case class MyTable (id: Int, imagesRanks: Seq[Option[ImageRank]])

implicit val propertyMyTableResult = GetResult(r => MyTable(r.<<, r.<<)
implicit val propertyImageRankResult = GetResult[Option[ImageRank]] { r => ImageRank(r.<<, r.<<)) }
```

What is the correct way to do it?

**UPDATE**

This wrap (following the answer from n1r3) is blocking me at the moment:

```
implicit val ImageRankWrapper: JdbcType[List[ImageRank]] = new SimpleArrayJdbcType[ImageRank]("image_rank[]").to(_.toList)
```

**UPDATE 2**

Still not sure what is wrong. I have added the code as you suggested, but it still complains with:

`could not find implicit value for parameter rconv: slick.jdbc.GetResult[database.rows.MyTable]`.

So I have added:

`implicit val myTableResult = GetResult[MyTable](r => MyTable(r.<<, r.<<))`

which returns:

```
diverging implicit expansion for type slick.jdbc.GetResult[T1]
starting with object GetStringOption in object GetResult
         r.<<, r.<<))
```

This is my configuration:

```
import com.github.tminglei.slickpg._
import database.rows.ImageRank

trait CustomPostgresProfile extends ExPostgresProfile
  with PgArraySupport
  with PgPlayJsonSupport
  with PgPostGISSupport
  with PgEnumSupport
  with PgDate2Support {

  // Use PostgreSQL JSONB support
  def pgjson = "jsonb"

  override val api = MyAPI
  object MyAPI extends API
    with ArrayImplicits
    with JsonImplicits
    with PostGISImplicits
    with DateTimeImplicits {
    implicit val imageRankListTypeMapper =
      new AdvancedArrayJdbcType[ImageRank]("image_rank",
        str => utils.SimpleArrayUtils.fromString[ImageRank](s => {
          val ImageRankRegex = "ImageRank\\((.*),(\\d+)\\)".r
          s match {
            case ImageRankRegex(imageUrl, thumbnailRank) =>
              ImageRank(imageUrl, thumbnailRank.toInt)
            case _ =>
              println(s"$s is not ImageRank")
              ImageRank("", 0)
          }
        })(str).orNull,
        imageRanks => utils.SimpleArrayUtils.mkString[ImageRank](_.toString)(imageRanks)
      ).to(_.toList)
  }
}

object CustomPostgresProfile extends CustomPostgresProfile


abstract class DatabaseProfile(val provider: DatabaseConfigProvider) {
  val config = provider.get[CustomPostgresProfile]
  val profile = config.profile
  val db = config.db
}

trait PropertyDataDatabase {
    self: DatabaseProfile =>
    .....
```

Comment: I'm not sure `Seq[Option[ImageRank]]`  is correct, don't you want `Option[Seq[ImageRank]]` or simply `Seq[ImageRank]`?

Comment: Using a regex kills mostly of the "safety" of typed languages. So I changed it to at least using "Option". Also, the values are not  always there. I have tweaked a bit the code in the 'Mapper' by Dmitri.

Comment: Right. But one can assume the database is a trusted system, no? And just throw a good old RuntimeException if it's not?

Comment: I have removed the "option" and reverted to the Dmytro code, but I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: Do you correctly import the implicit in scope?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: @Randomize Try
`implicit val propertyImageRankResult = GetResult(r => ImageRank(r.nextString, r.nextInt))`
  `implicit val propertyImageRankOptionResult = GetResult(r => Some(r.<<[ImageRank]) : Option[ImageRank])`
  `implicit val propertyImageRankOptionSeqResult = GetResult(r => Seq(r.<<[Option[ImageRank]]))`
  `implicit val propertyMyTableResult = GetResult(r => MyTable(r.nextInt, r.<<[Seq[Option[ImageRank]]]))`

Answer (score 3):

The best would be for you to use this excellent library: https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg

If you would rather implement it yourself, have a look at the source code (https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/com/github/tminglei/slickpg/array) and get what you want from there.

Comment: Thank you. In the link you put, there is an example of `MarketFinancialProduct` as list element. How do I replace it with my `ImageRank`?

Comment: @Randomize See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46814905/5249621).

Answer (score 2):

What is `ImageRank`? Write its definition. I presume it's a case class

```
case class ImageRank(imageUrl: String, thumbnailRank: Int)
```

I guess that besides `slick-pg` mapper for specific array

```
implicit val imageRankListTypeMapper =
  new AdvancedArrayJdbcType[ImageRank]("image_rank",
    str => utils.SimpleArrayUtils.fromString[ImageRank](s => {
      val ImageRankRegex = "ImageRank\\((.*),(\\d+)\\)".r
      s match {
        case ImageRankRegex(imageUrl, thumbnailRank) =>
          ImageRank(imageUrl, thumbnailRank.toInt)
        case _ =>
          println(s"$s is not ImageRank")
          ImageRank("", 0)
      }
    })(str).orNull,
    imageRanks => utils.SimpleArrayUtils.mkString[ImageRank](_.toString)(imageRanks)
  ).to(_.toList)
```

you should define `slick` mapper for `ImageRank` like

```
case class LiftedImageRank(imageUrl: Rep[String], thumbnailRank: Rep[Int])
implicit object ImageRankShape extends CaseClassShape(LiftedImageRank.tupled, ImageRank.tupled)
```

Documentation is [here](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/userdefined.html#monomorphic-case-classes).

`SimpleArrayJdbcType` has `String` argument meaning [SQL **base** type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-type-system.html#idm46046864234896) so I guess `"image_rank[]"` won't work.

Also `SimpleArrayJdbcType` works with arrays whose base type `T` is standard and for which `ElemWitness[T]` is defined in `slick-pg`. Since there is no `ElemWitness[ImageRank]` you should use `AdvancedArrayJdbcType`.