# How to map text ARRAY in Postgres to Scala Slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I have the following column in my postgres table:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
    ALTER COLUMN test_field TYPE text ARRAY USING test_field::text ARRAY
```

When I regenerate the Slick schema directly from my postgres table, I have the following"

```
*  @param test_field Database column test_field SqlType(_text), Length(2147483647,false), Default(None) */

  case class MyTable(id: java.util.UUID, created: Option[java.sql.Timestamp] = None, test_field: Option[String] = None)

  /** GetResult implicit for fetching MyTable objects using plain SQL queries */

  implicit def GetResultTable(implicit e0: GR[java.util.UUID], e1: GR[Option[java.sql.Timestamp]], e2: GR[String] = GR{
    prs => import prs._
    MyTable(<<[java.util.UUID], <<?[java.sql.Timestamp],<<?[String])
  }
```

I am not sure as why the field is not recognised as `Option[Array[String]]` , Where did I go wrong?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg is a good place to start - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808137/how-to-express-postgres-arrays-with-scala-slick

Comment: Thanks, so I am now using slick-pg and created the postgresProfile exactly like the example in the Github repository, but ```_text``` is recognised as the following:

``` val test_field: Rep[Option[scala.collection.Seq]] = column[Option[scala.collection.Seq]]("test_field", O.Default(None))``` lamenting ```Type scala.collection.Seq takes type parameters```. If I pas String as a type parameter then complains about implicit. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I employed `slick-pg` and created my own `MyPostgresProfile` as detailed in the project's README. It turned out that there are issues with Slick dealing with `text[]` in Postgres and despite `slick-pg` does support Arrays:

[https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/com/github/tminglei/slickpg/array][1]

When generating the table, such array was actually seen as a `Seq`

I ended up changing the data type in Postgres from Array to jsonb and it is deal with beautifully by the plugin using `JValue`.